# SQL query does not perform DESC correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a problem that I do not know how to solve.
I have this query:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM transfer_centre WHERE status = 'out' ORDER BY pris DESC";`

And I have four values as `pris` in my db:
`0, 4, 8, 26`

So, as the query states they should be listed as such:

- 26
- 8
- 4
- 0

But somehow it sees the 26 value as 2.6 (i guess?) and therefore 26 is between 4 and 0?

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: what is the data type of `pris`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your column is a VARCHAR type and  it is ordering like it. When you order a VARCHAR, you go from left to right on each character, so 26 is between 0 and 4.

You can try this, if you can't change your schema:

```
SELECT * FROM transfer_centre WHERE status = 'out'
    ORDER BY CAST(pris as SIGNED INTEGER) DESC
```

**NOTE:** This is not even close from an ideal solution! If the column is  treated as  a number, you should change the schema applying the right type.

Comment: @M.Pedersen this answer helps you to kill your database.

Comment: Yes, if this column should be treated as NUMBER, you should change your schema.